# Gauss forward and backward elimination

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to use the Gauss forward and backward elimination so that at the end I dont need to do a backstubsitution because I have everywhere zeros in my matrix except for my diagonal..... but something is going wrong, everytime I try my code I don't get all the zeros in the corner, but if I try my code seperately the only forward elimination works and the only backward elimination too.....

```
clc, close all, clear *
%Input Matrix
A = input('Enter a matrix: ');
b = input('Enter the result vector: ');
% for example this two:
% A= [1 2 3; 2 1 1; 6 -7 5];
% b= [3; 2; 5];
Ab= [A, b];


%%%%%%%%%% gauss elimination forward & backward elimination%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Forward elimination
% A(1,1) is pivot
factor = A(2,1)/A(1,1);
Ab(2,:) = Ab(2,:) - factor*Ab(1,:);
factor = A(3,1)/A(1,1);
Ab(3,:) = Ab(3,:) - factor*Ab(1,:); 
% A(2,2) is pivot
factor = Ab(3,2)/Ab(2,2);
Ab(3,:) = Ab(3,:) - factor*Ab(2,:);

%Backward elimination
% A(3,3) is pivot
factor = A(2,3)/A(3,3);
Ab(2,:) = Ab(2,:) - factor*Ab(3,:);
factor = A(1,3)/A(3,3);
Ab(1,:) = Ab(1,:) - factor*Ab(3,:); 
% A(2,2) is pivot
factor = Ab(1,2)/Ab(2,2);
Ab(1,:) = Ab(1,:) - factor*Ab(2,:);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be basing your `factor` on the `Ab` matrix rather than the `A` matrix; your (3,2), (2,3), (1,3) and (1,2) values are going to change as time goes on. It looks like you started to fix this issue during your forward elimination, since you included the Ab properly in that factor calculation. 
As a side note, you may wish to normalize at the end by dividing each row of Ab by the value on the "diagonal"

Comment: Yep! In the future, a good way to troubleshoot a short code like this is trying to walk through it line by line, and see at which step the output becomes different from what you think should be happening. In this case, you would notice when your fourth factor is unexpectedly equal to -5. [Which is how I troubleshot it]